# MongoDB Diagram Design Tool

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema

Planning a project using MongoDB and looking for a tool to map out the database.

Any suggestions of a database design tool similar to http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/ that specifically supports MongoDB?

Thanks

Comment: There are no schemas in Mongo...

Comment: That's a separate discussion. But I am looking for a design tool to map out the collections and documents within a Mongo DB.

Comment: you might consider modifying your question, since obviously no 'schema diagram' tool exists for a database without schemas.

Comment: @RexM Disagree, Rex.  MongoDB does have schemas.  They may be dynamic, but there are schemas.  I don't think Hutch is talking about a tool to generate schema code.  I think he's looking for a way to communicate his design.

Comment: @Hutch: Are you looking for a data modeling tool?  I haven't been able to find one either that effectively captures json-style design, but am currently looking into faking it with XML modeling tools like Altova's suite.

Comment: MongoDB is a document based Database using Json Objects. Why not use a JSON shema editor?

http://jsonschema.net/#/

and then use for example a tool to graphicly display json shemas to communicate it:

http://som-research.uoc.edu/tools/jsonDiscoverer/#/advanced

Comment: Adding it in case anyone needs it. DBSchema (http://www.dbschema.com/) seems is the tool you are looking for. I quote from their website: "You may ask how is this possible, since MongoDB use no schema as relational databases does. Well, DbSchema does discover the schema by scanning the data. What to have to do is to start DbSchema, connect to the database ( provide the host name where the database is running ) and the job is done."

Comment: Adding another tool - [Moon Modeler](https://www.datensen.com) is a diagram design tool that supports MongoDB and Mongoose. You can use it to draw diagrams and visualize MongoDB structures.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a way to create a data model to communicate your design, there are no tools out there specifically created to model json-structured data.

However, you could use UML tools or XML design tools to create your models.  I've been less than satisfied with both methods, but it's all I have until some awesome developer builds a json-based data modeling tool.

Answer (score 2):

As @Rex M says in a comment to your question, there are no schemas in Mongo.

There are tools such as [MongoVUE](http://blog.mongovue.com/) which might be of use however.

Comment: Agreed. Looking for a MongoDB version of http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising (have not tried it yet):
http://3t.io/schema-explorer/
http://3t.io/

Here are more Mongo tools:
http://mongodb-tools.com/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can use any database modeling tool.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design